# How to test js modules written as amd module for browser with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, phantomjs, casperjs

I've spent enough time today trying to create unit test to cover my js modules written as amd module. Unfortunately, I gave up.
Of course you can't just `require` you js file because the `define` function will be undefined. 
I've run my test scripts by following line:

```
casperjs test test.js
```

Then, I've tried to inject all scripts to empty page and evaluate it:

```
var
  casper = require("casper").create({
    clientScripts: [
      'require.js',
      'config.js',
      'MyJSClass.js'
    ],
    logLevel: "debug",
    verbose: true
  });
casper.test.begin('charts created', 1, function(test) {

  casper.start().then(function() {
    require('utils').dump(this.evaluate(function() {
      return this.requirejs('MyJSClass');
    }));
  })
    .run(function() {
      test.done();
    });
});
```

result was `null`.

After that I created an empty html file and loaded all scripts there. The result is the same =( I can't get my module to test

Any ideas?

P.S. casper ver 1.1-dev, phantomjs 1.9.2